# SNMP Port 161 address already in used error in UBUNTU Linux OS

Tags: linux, .net-core, snmp

I have an c#.net core console application in which SNMP socket is binding to port 161(hard coded value). Application is getting error at the runtime.

Error: "Address already in use"

Currently 161 port address is used by another process SNMPD. I tried to kill the SNMPD process,but again it is running automatically.

How to kill SNMPD process? Please help me on this issue...

Comment: Please go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and ask how to uninstall/disable snmpd instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop `snmpd` with `sudo systemctl stop snmpd`, but if you are not using it you might be better off uninstalling it.